# Powershell parsing regex in text file

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a text file:

```
Text.txt

2015-08-31 05:55:54,881 INFO   (ClientThread.java:173) - Login successful for user = Test, client = 123.456.789.100:12345
2015-08-31 05:56:51,354 INFO   (ClientThread.java:325) - Closing connection 123.456.789.100:12345
```

I would like output to be:

```
2015-08-31 05:55:54 Login Test 123.456.789.100
2015-08-31 05:56:51 Closing connection 123.456.789.100
```

Code:

```
$files = Get-Content "Text.txt"
$grep = $files | Select-String "serviceClient:" , "Unregistered" |  
Where {$_ -match '^(\S+)+\s+([^,]+).*?-\s+(\w+).*?(\S+)$' } |
Foreach {"$($matches[1..4])"} | Write-Host
```

How can I do it with the current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another group and make it optional.

`^(\S+)+\s+([^,]+).*?-\s+(\w+)(?:.*?=\s+(\w+))?.*?(\S+?)(?::\d+)?$`

```
 ^ 
 ( \S+ )+                      # (1)
 \s+ 
 ( [^,]+ )                     # (2)
 .*? - \s+ 
 ( \w+ )                       # (3)
 (?:
      .*? = \s+ 
      ( \w+ )                       # (4)
 )?
 .*? 
 ( \S+? )                      # (5)
 (?: : \d+ )?
 $
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 121 ) 
2015-08-31 05:55:54,881 INFO   (ClientThread.java:173) - Login successful for user = Test, client = 123.456.789.100:12345  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 10 ) 
2015-08-31  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 11 , len 8 ) 
05:55:54  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 57 , len 5 ) 
Login  
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 85 , len 4 ) 
Test  
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 100 , len 15 ) 
123.456.789.100  

----------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 123 , len 97 ) 
2015-08-31 05:56:51,354 INFO   (ClientThread.java:325) - Closing connection 123.456.789.100:12345  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 123 , len 10 ) 
2015-08-31  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 134 , len 8 ) 
05:56:51  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 180 , len 7 ) 
Closing  
 **  Grp 4 -  NULL 
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 199 , len 15 ) 
123.456.789.100
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what it means? Why make it optional?

Comment: @SumoStash - This is just the regex you've started with. I've added another optional `= ..` field because its optional in your input. I've also added an optional `: \d` at the end to exclude it from capture group 5, because it was omitted in your output (but is part of the input).. Finally, made all the dot's non-greedy.

Comment: This answered my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: If it solved your immediate problem be sure to mark it as answered, if it didn't no need..

Comment: I think there is an extra space between: Closing   123.456.789.100  
How to remove that? It would be from group 4 to group 5.

Comment: @SumoStash - Not sure what you mean. None of the capture groups allow whitespace. If you're talking about the `output` text, the trailing spaces are part of a graphic ender (from [here](http://www.regexformat.com)) , not part of the output.

Comment: @SumoStash - Show the offending string in quotes.